# Swift: write JSON and save to iPhone File locally

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am learning how to write JSON format data to an iPhone. So with one button clicked, I want to save those data to the iPhone.  I looked a simple look on how to write some simple text and saved it to the iPhone file and it worked. However, I tried to apply the same idea to JSON data but still haven't figure out. I tried:

Rather than having contents equal to some written text, I tried to put it as my data (jsondata).
But it does not seem working with

try jsondata.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)

```
@IBAction func writeFiles(_ sender: Any) {
        let file = "\(UUID().uuidString).txt"
               let contents = "Testing"
               let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
               let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
               do {
                   try contents.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
               }
               catch {
                   print("Error: \(error)")
               }
   }
```

Sorry I am a bit new and learning Swift at the moment

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple project for you to clone or browse the source files
  https://github.com/eSpecialized/WriteJsonToFiles

The View Controller contains the example;
https://github.com/eSpecialized/WriteJsonToFiles/blob/master/WriteToFiles/ViewController.swift

**Basically you need to do a few steps for writing;**

1. Assemble your objects (Strings etc).
2. Convert to JSONEncoded Data using the JSONEncoder.
3. The actual 'Data' Object can write it's binary content to storage.

**To read the data;**

1. You need a JSONDecoder.
2. You need the FileContents in memory using Data(contents:...)
3. Decode the in-memory data back into the object like it was stored.

A more complicated example of reading and writing JSON to a Web Service API is on Medium here > https://medium.com/better-programming/json-parsing-in-swift-2498099b78f

The concepts are the same, the destination changes from a file in the users document folder to a web service API.  I feel that it is adequate to get you started with reading and writing JSON.

The Medium article goes a step further with introducing you to Data Models and reading and writing those Data Model Structs using the Codable protocol.

Enjoy! :)

Comment: Thank so much for the example. I am trying to play around this in the simulator. I tried writing on the bar and save it. However I cannot find those result in the iPhone file? I am a bit new to this. Could you explain how to" Assemble your objects (Strings etc)."?

Comment: Hii Bill, I am trying to follow your example. But the problem I have is that if I have a defined JSON structure, how can I praise my capture to the file? (not from a web API )

Comment: Q) I cannot find those results in the iPhone file?
A) Now in 2020 with Xcode 11.x, and Mac OS Catalina, iTunes is not available and can no longer be used on a Mac.  Instead, you will need to use Finder to see App Files on your iPhone.

1. You will need a plist entry in the App.
Application supports iTunes file sharing = YES
The actual Key raw format;
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
 <true/>

2. Re-Run the WriteJsonToFiles
3. Now you can See the files when you select in Finder;
  Locations
    > your iPhone
    select the "Files" Tab
    Find the App name, and there is your data.

Comment: "how can I praise my capture to the file"
I don't understand this question.

Comment: I updated the Repo I posted with a screenshot and the info.plist changes for accessing files of an App.